# Creating .edmx file programmatically

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data, edmx

Is there any way to create edmx file programmatically without configuring manually.

My requirement is like this: I have to create a website dynamically. In that website I have to use EF files. ie. I have to create edmx file programatically and not manually. I have the Database name, connection string, server name, username, password and all with me. 
Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution. The following link helps those who want to create edmx file programmatically in VS 2012.

https://bitbucket.org/cincura_net/edmgen2/

This is a new thread. Will be helpful for those who found EdmxGen2 is not compatable with vs 2010.

Thanks,
Sujith.S

Comment: is there any link for EDMX6, above link is only for EDMX1/2/3. and in current scenario edmx 3 is out dated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have a look at edmgen2.exe for info on how to create the edmx programitically. http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EdmGen2

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, here we have to give one edmx file as input. right? But I didn't have one edmx for giving input. I wish to give the server name, dbname, username and password as input. I want edmx as output. Is there any way to achieve this??

Comment: Yes, edmgen2 can do that - You can just give a connection string, provider name and path to the generated edmx file as input, as you can see in the project: https://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#1118657

Comment: I have no idea, only used the source as shown in the link, and that works for me, but I am only using it with SQL Server Compact

Comment: Hi, I have created one edmx now. But the problem now I face is it is not compatable with the Visual Studio 2012 framework. how can I make this compatable to VS 2012?

Comment: Create one with the designer compare the xml, then change the generated edmx to match.

Comment: Sorry ErikEJ, that doesnot match with my requirement. I have to create it dynamically. Cant do manual comparison after creating.

Comment: I know, it was just a suggestion to fix the namespace issue.

Comment: Hi ErikEJ, I have found the solution. I have answered for my thread. I hope this may be helpful for you too.